# Unable to use Colorbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using Colorbox for jQuery. I downloaded the plugin from http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Below is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#gallery').colorbox();
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>JQuery - Chapter 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/colorbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="JS/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="gallery" href="images/dog.jpeg">Dog</a>
    <a id="gallery" href="images/horse.jpg">Horse</a>
    <a id="gallery" href="images/tree.jpg">Tree</a>
</body>
```

When I click on the image name, it doesnt fire the colorbox() method. Rather it takes me to the image source.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned, each element must have a unique ID. If you want to group them, you should use a Class attribute. This is also how it's outlined in the guide: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.gallery').colorbox({
    rel: "group1"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a id="gallery-1" class="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/t5L4otE.jpg">Dog</a>
<a id="gallery-2" class="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/wZHWtP3.jpg">Horse</a>
<a id="gallery-3" class="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/ihH1kfg.jpg">Tree</a>
```

This snippet works as expected. jQuery must be loaded BEFORE the plugin. Since you are loading Bootstrap (which uses jQuery) and jQuery library, you might get some weird results. So I would investigate which is the better library to use.

> **rel**
>
> This can be used as an anchor rel alternative for Colorbox. This allows the user to group any combination of elements together for a gallery, or to override an existing rel so elements are not grouped together. `$("a.gallery").colorbox({rel:"group1"});` **Note:** The value can also be set to 'nofollow' to disable grouping.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 modifications required:

1) Provide unique id to all anchor tags like gallery1, gallery2, gallery3, and

2) add click js function to invoke colorbox on each anchor tag

Like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function colorbox1()
   {  
     $('#gallery1').colorbox();
     return false;
   }

  function colorbox2()
   {  
     $('#gallery2').colorbox();
     return false;
   }

   function colorbox3()
   {  
     $('#gallery3').colorbox();
     return false;
   }
</script>
```

and in HTML:

```
<body>
    <a id="gallery1" click="return colorbox1();" href="images/dog.jpeg">Dog</a>
    <a id="gallery2" click="return colorbox1();" href="images/horse.jpg">Horse</a>
    <a id="gallery3" click="return colorbox1();" href="images/tree.jpg">Tree</a>
</body>
```

Comment: I am trying to display the images as a group. Tried the code. Not working.